# my react project compiles but the browser gives me error

Tags: reactjs

[image]

my browser gives me this error but vs code doesn't show any errors
it stops at return but the error indicates there's something wrong with render
it looks like the problem is with render but I don't understand what's wrong with it
here at line 37 nothing looks wrong but the compiler stops here
here's my code:

```
      import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Form extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    email: ''
    }
  }



  handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const{qrUrl}=this.props.qrUrl;
    axios.get(`${qrUrl}`)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(this.qrUrl);
  }).then({
      method: "POST", 
      url:"http://localhost:3002/send", 
      data:  this.state
    }).then((response)=>{
      if (response.data.status === 'success'){
        alert("Message Sent."); 
        this.resetForm()
      }else if(response.data.status === 'fail'){
        alert("Message failed to send.")
      }
    })
  }



  render() {

    return(
    <div className="App">
    <form id="contact-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} method="POST">


    <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" className="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.onEmailChange.bind(this)} />
    </div>

    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handle.bind(this)}>Submit</button>
    </form>
    </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the syntax, however you didn't declared the state on your component so this is why you are having this error message, this.state is undefined so it cannot read the property email of something undefined, you need to initiate the state on your constructor

Comment: I added the email state now and refreshed

Comment: could you please update your question with the changes

Comment: in your code you have those events onClick={this.handle.bind(this)} and onChange={this.onEmailChange.bind(this)} but in your code i cannot see those two function, also try to kill the server and run it again, if your code is missing something here please update it with what you have exactly on your project

Comment: you are welcome mohamed happy to help, don't forget to accept the answer :)